# Using associated constant in a default trait implementation

Tags: rust, constants, traits

I would like to accomplish the following

```rust
trait Trait {
    const CONST: f64;
    fn fun(&self) -> f64 {
        1.0 + self.CONST
    }
}
```

and then define a bunch of `struct`-s implementing the `Trait` with different constants.
Such as

```rust
struct Struct {}
impl Trait for Struct {
    const CONST: f64 = 1.0;
}
```

Unfortunately the former snippet does not compile. I can have both an associated constant and a default implementation, but seemingly I cannot use the const in the default implementation.
Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The constant does not belong to a specific instance, but to the type itself. You must use `Self::CONST`:

```rust
trait Trait {
    const CONST: f64;
    fn fun(&self) -> f64 {
        1.0 + Self::CONST
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67da7266e61f48bd06497f40fcfbae15))

Comment: Great! thanks! Now I can safely (and should) remove `&self` from the definition of `fun` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a30371e76f36fa10ee64724ed196a46)). Does it even make sense to ever have `&self` in a default implementation of a function within the trait?

Comment: @VictorErmolaev yes, for example the default implementation of `Iterator::nth` calls `self.next()` repeatedly. It probably only makes sense when there is at least one non-defaulted function in the trait though.